# Pygame pygame.Rect how to add text into a rect and move it around the screen?

Tags: python, pygame

Trying to add text into a rectangle and move the rectangle around the screen using the arrow keys. I want to make it so the text doesn't go off the edge. So far I had it working without putting it into a Rect but I want to make the Rect function work. Right now the text just bounces back and I don't know how big to make the original rectangle that corresponds with the font size.

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600),0)
pygame.display.set_caption("Basic Pygame Text With Rects")

width = screen.get_width()
height = screen.get_height()
x = int(width/2)
y = int(height/2)
dx = 0
dy = 0
speed = 10
oldx = x
oldy = y

WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
colour = BLACK

textRect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 30, 10)

screen.fill(WHITE)
pygame.display.update()

# first set up your font (typeface and size)
# I have created two different ones here that can be used later in the program
fontTitle = pygame.font.SysFont("arial",10)

main = True
while main:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type ==pygame.QUIT:
            main = False
        if event.type ==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                dx = 0
                dy = -speed
                colour = RED
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                dx = 0
                dy = speed
                colour = BLUE
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:     # note: this section of code
                dx = -speed                     # doesn't have to change from
                dy = 0
                colour = GREEN
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                dx = speed
                dy = 0
                colour = YELLOW
            elif event.key == pygame.K_c:
                x = screen.get_width() / 2
                y = screen.get_height() / 2
                colour = BLACK
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                dx = 0
                dy = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                dx = 0
                dy = 0
    screen.fill(WHITE)


    oldx = x
    oldy = y
    textRect.move_ip(dx,dy)

    if (textRect.y <= 0) or (textRect.y >= height):
        dy = 0
        textRect.y = int(oldy)
    if (textRect.x <= 20) or (textRect.x >= width - 20):
        dx = 0
        textRect.x = int(oldx)
    # render the text into an image of the text, colour is red
    # create a rect with it's centre placed at centre of screen
    # blit the image to memory, it will display upon next update
    textTitle = fontTitle.render("Go Huskies", True, colour)
    drawText = textTitle.get_rect(center=(textRect.x, textRect.y))

    screen.blit(textTitle, textRect)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: surface with text and `Rect` with its position are two separated elements. You use them both to `blit()` text on screen.

Comment: why don't you use `drawText` to draw it `screen.blit(textTitle, drawText)` and later use only `drawText` to move it - it has size of text.

Comment: to center on screen you can use `center=screen.get_rect().center`

Answer (score 1):

You could generate text at start to get its size

```
fontTitle = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 10)
textTitle = fontTitle.render("Go Huskies", True, colour)
rectTitle = textTitle.get_rect(center=screen.get_rect().center)
```

and later use only this `rectTitle` to move it and check collision with borders - and don't create new `textTitle.get_rect()`

```
screen.blit(textTitle, rectTitle)
```

`Rect` has `.top`, `.bottom`, `.left`, `.right`, `.centerx`, `.centery` which you can use to check collision

```
oldx, oldy = rectTitle.center

rectTitle.move_ip(dx, dy)

if (rectTitle.top <= 0) or (rectTitle.bottom >= height):
    dy = 0
    rectTitle.centery = oldy

if (rectTitle.left <= 0) or (rectTitle.right >= width):
    dx = 0
    rectTitle.centerx = oldx
```

---

```
import pygame
import sys

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

# --- classes --- (CamelCaseNames)

# empty

# --- functions --- (lower_case_names)

# empty

# --- main --- (lower_case_names)

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600),0)
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

pygame.display.set_caption("Basic Pygame Text With Rects")

x, y = screen_rect.center
width, height = screen_rect.size
dx = 0
dy = 0
speed = 10
oldx = x
oldy = y

colour = BLACK

fontTitle = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 10)
textTitle = fontTitle.render("Go Huskies", True, colour)
rectTitle = textTitle.get_rect(center=screen_rect.center)

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

main = True
while main:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type ==pygame.QUIT:
            main = False
        if event.type ==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                dx = 0
                dy = -speed
                colour = RED
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                dx = 0
                dy = speed
                colour = BLUE
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:     # note: this section of code
                dx = -speed                     # doesn't have to change from
                dy = 0
                colour = GREEN
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                dx = speed
                dy = 0
                colour = YELLOW
            elif event.key == pygame.K_c:
                x, y = screen_rect.center
                colour = BLACK
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                dx = 0
                dy = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                dx = 0
                dy = 0

    # - moves/updates -

    oldx, oldy = rectTitle.center
    rectTitle.move_ip(dx,dy)

    if (rectTitle.top <= 0) or (rectTitle.bottom >= height):
        dy = 0
        rectTitle.centery = oldy

    if (rectTitle.left <= 0) or (rectTitle.right >= width):
        dx = 0
        rectTitle.centerx = oldx

    textTitle = fontTitle.render("Go Huskies", True, colour)

    # - draws -

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    screen.blit(textTitle, rectTitle)
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(25) # slow down to 25 FPS (frames per seconds)

# - end -

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

---

If you want to move text with background rectangle then you can create `Surface()`, fill it with some color and then blit text on it

at start:

```
rectRect = pygame.surface.Surface
fontTitle = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 10)
textTitle = fontTitle.render("Go Huskies", True, colour)
rectTitle = textTitle.get_rect(center=screen_rect.center)

item_surface = pygame.surface.Surface(rectTitle.size)
item_surface.fill(RED)
item_surface.blit(textTitle, (0,0))

textTitle = item_surface
```

in loop:

```
textTitle = fontTitle.render("Go Huskies", True, colour)

item_surface = pygame.surface.Surface(rectTitle.size)
item_surface.fill(RED)
item_surface.blit(textTitle, (0,0))
textTitle = item_surface
```

Full code:

```
import pygame
import sys

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

# --- classes --- (CamelCaseNames)

# empty

# --- functions --- (lower_case_names)

# empty

# --- main --- (lower_case_names)

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600),0)
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

pygame.display.set_caption("Basic Pygame Text With Rects")

x, y = screen_rect.center
width, height = screen_rect.size
dx = 0
dy = 0
speed = 10
oldx = x
oldy = y

colour = BLACK

rectRect = pygame.surface.Surface
fontTitle = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 10)
textTitle = fontTitle.render("Go Huskies", True, colour)
rectTitle = textTitle.get_rect(center=screen_rect.center)

item_surface = pygame.surface.Surface(rectTitle.size)
item_surface.fill(RED)
item_surface.blit(textTitle, (0,0))

textTitle = item_surface

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

main = True
while main:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type ==pygame.QUIT:
            main = False
        if event.type ==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                dx = 0
                dy = -speed
                colour = RED
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                dx = 0
                dy = speed
                colour = BLUE
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:     # note: this section of code
                dx = -speed                     # doesn't have to change from
                dy = 0
                colour = GREEN
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                dx = speed
                dy = 0
                colour = YELLOW
            elif event.key == pygame.K_c:
                x, y = screen_rect.center
                colour = BLACK
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                dx = 0
                dy = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                dx = 0
                dy = 0

    # - moves -

    oldx, oldy = rectTitle.center
    rectTitle.move_ip(dx,dy)

    if (rectTitle.top <= 0) or (rectTitle.bottom >= height):
        dy = 0
        rectTitle.centery = oldy

    if (rectTitle.left <= 0) or (rectTitle.right >= width):
        dx = 0
        rectTitle.centerx = oldx

    textTitle = fontTitle.render("Go Huskies", True, colour)

    item_surface = pygame.surface.Surface(rectTitle.size)
    item_surface.fill(RED)
    item_surface.blit(textTitle, (0,0))

    textTitle = item_surface

    # - draws -

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    screen.blit(textTitle, rectTitle)
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(25) # slow down to 25 FPS (frames per seconds)

# - end - 

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

[image]